# reloadData() doesn't work with refreshControl

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, reloaddata, uirefreshcontrol

I have UICollectionView that manages a lot of cells. When I delete a cell, I would like the cell disappears with a refreshControl. But I don't understand why the reloadData does not act. If anyone can help me thank you in advance.

In my view didLoad :

```
self.collectionView!.alwaysBounceVertical = true
let refresher = UIRefreshControl()
refresher.tintColor = MyColor.Color
refresher.addTarget(self, action: #selector(PublicListController.refreshStream), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
refreshControl = refresher
collectionView!.addSubview(refreshControl!)

collectionView.dataSource = self
self.populateDataBest()
```

My simply function :

```
func refreshStream() {
    collectionView?.reloadData()
    refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
}
```

I complete my CollectionView with the method populateDataBest :

```
 func populateDataBest() {
    self.videosService.get(true, completionHandler: {
        videosBest, error in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            if error != nil {
                if error!.code == -999 {
                    return
                }
                self.displayError(informations.LocalizedConnectionError)
                return
            }
                self.bestClip = videosBest
                for (indexBest, _) in (self.bestClip?.enumerate())! {
                    let videoBest:Clip = self.bestClip![indexBest]
                    self.pictureArrayVideo.addObject(["clip": videoBest, "group": "BEST"])
                }
                 self.dataSource.updateData(self.pictureArrayVideo)
                 self.collectionView.reloadData()
        })
    })
}
```

And the first reload work at the end of my method populateDataBest..

**EDIT :**

I try to implement function who remove my element (I put 0 in parameters on remove method just for my test for the moment)

```
func refreshStream() {
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.remove(0)
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    })
     self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

func remove(i: Int) {
    self.listForPager.removeAtIndex(i)
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: i, inSection: 0)
    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates({
        self.collectionView.deleteItemsAtIndexPaths(NSArray(object: indexPath) as! [NSIndexPath])
        }, completion: {
            (finished: Bool) in
            self.collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths(self.collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems())
    })
}
```

And I have this error after

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (8) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (8), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 1 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
```

---

Someone know why and can help me plz ?

Thx in advance.

Comment: No need to add "swift IOS" to the title, you already have those tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are riding your collection from an array you should also delete the item for the line will disappear and finally to reload.

Comment: It is a array that I get with an request on a server. But when I disconnect and reconnect the application, the element disappear (without making modifications in the array). I would just avoid disconnecting and reconnecting  to reload and therefore use the refreshControl. I have to remove the element of the table then?

Comment: Yes. you must remove the element of the table!